# XAMPP Ignores Document Root; Redirects to 'localhost/dashboard'

Tags: php, apache, laravel, xampp, localhost

I have two computers, a laptop & desktop, with seemingly identical setups:

- Running local server via XAMPP (for Windows, v 7.0.13)
- Laravel-based project
- In `httpd.conf`, `DocumentRoot` is set to D:/xampp/htdocs/site-folder/public

On the laptop, everything works as expected; visiting `localhost` in Chrome hits Laravel's `public` folder and the application fires up like it should. On the desktop, however, I get redirected to `localhost/dashboard` when I visit `localhost`. Typing out the full address (ie, `localhost/site-folder/public`) works, but all links are broken, as they expect the `site-folder/public` directory to be the root.

My assumption—and I hope I'm wrong about this—is that there are a lot of potential configuration settings that might be off. Any ideas on what might cause this, or how to go about debugging? Thanks in advance for any thoughts/suggestions!

Comment: Check the `host` file in your desktop laptop, maybe you have some redirection there :)

Comment: Thanks for that, good suggestion! Already checked both, though. Assuming we're talking about `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`, they're entirely commented out, on both devices..

Comment: Have you restarted the server since you made the changes?

Comment: Yup, also a good thought. But yes, each time I make a change, I'm restarting Apache via the XAMPP control panel.

Comment: Are those clean xampp installations?...are you sure that you don't have any virtual host in your desktop computer?

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure...actually did a fresh install of XAMPP on the desktop, to make sure that wasn't a problem. How can I double-check that, though?

Comment: The `D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` file is all commented-out as well, if that's what you're referring to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be the result of middleware I had in place, which required a secure connection. The middleware worked fine/as expected, but the `httpd-ssl.conf` file needed the updated project path. In case somebody else is experiencing a similar problem, try this:

- Find the comment **# General setup for the virtual host**
- Change `DocumentRoot` to the same project path used in your
  httpd.conf

Appreciate all comments on the original question!